# Why didn’t Ronan just sneak onto Xandar?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

Ronan is a super-powerful, impossible-to-kill ultra bad guy. So why did he

> ...need a ship to get the Infinity Stone (the purple thing) to the Nova Corps planet? Why not just jump out? Or send his flagship in as a distraction, and land in a fighter on the other side? All he has to do is touch the stone to the planet right? Planets are pretty big...

It bugs me that the Guardians actually had no chance at all had Ronan used any kind of strategy other than 'point the ship at all their guns, then go forward'.

Comment: Thanos wasn't directly involved in the primary events of *Guardians*. He sent Ronan and Nebula to carry out his instructions.

Comment: 1. You are talking about Ronan, not Thanos. 2. What's the point of creating distraction when you are super confident that nothing can stand a chance in front of you?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking. Sounds to me more like a rant than a question. Please, clarify.

Comment: updated with proper name, superheroes blend together in my head oops

Answer (score 7):

As I understood the film, Ronan’s beef with Xandar was that he was bitter about the peace treaty his race had signed with theirs. He did not want the war between their people to end; he wanted vengeance on them.

As such, he didn’t want to just achieve the destruction of the planet’s inhabitants in the quickest, most efficient way possible. He wanted to stand before the populace and see them tremble before his might, and then kill them. Arriving in a big scary-looking ship gets you more attention than flying in solo.

And as you say, he’s also *extremely* powerful. He’s already killed many people personally (e.g. Drax’s wife and child), and now he possesses (and is actually capable of wielding) an Infinity Stone. He’s pretty arrogant at this point — he was confident enough to threaten Thanos.

He doesn’t think anyone stands a chance of stopping him, so why bother with strategy or trickery? Xandar is pretty much just the first step towards him conquering the galaxy. All he wants to do is walk in and lay the smackdown on them.

(One last point — if you’re asking practically why does he need a ship to travel to the planet, it’s not clear that the Power Stone gives the bearer the ability to fly through space unaided. He may well have actually needed his ship in order to arrive at Xandar, at least in any reasonable time frame.)

Comment: Good answer. Much like Loki in Avengers, he doesn't just want to defeat them... he wants to be SEEN defeating them.